# Issue with CSS Transition and the Label of a Checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label, css-transitions

I want to change the position of my label when the checkbox is checked. This works fine if I don't transition the `top` offset property of my label. However, if I add a transition to this value (see the commented code), click on the label and don't move the cursor of my mouse the label seems that is still on hover state. That means, even though I don't hover on it, the cursor is a pointer and the background-color green (hover state of label).

If you see [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davis88/pn3bqmj9/9/), you'll understand what I mean.

My HTML code is the following:

```
<section>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
    <label for="checkbox_id">Click me</label>
    <div> 
        <a href="">This is the first link</a>
        <a href="">This is the second link</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
label, a {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 10px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    background: tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
   /*transition: top .3s ease;*/  
}
label:hover {
    background: green;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    top: 100%;
}
a {
    display: block;
    background: tomato;
}
a:first-child {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Once transitioned, it only waits for slightest of movements from mouse pointer to change its colour right and you do not want this behaviour? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Actually, what I want is to behave just like without the transition. Otherwise, I have to move the mouse in order to achieve that behavior.

Comment: And would you mind a little bit of jQuery to solve that?

Comment: Well, I could use jQuery but what I really want to know is why that happens. I searched around the web, but I didn't manage to find a similar question or something like that. It is strange why that happens only when you add transitions.

Comment: I do not think it is strange considering it is the slightest of movement of mouse that is required afterwards that sets everything to *normal* again and perhaps people are just accustomed to seeing this behaviour. I personally think that it is just a normal behaviour. I could be wrong about it.

Comment: As mentioned I cannot understand why this doesn't happen when you do not have a transition.

Answer (score 1):

So, a little bit of jQuery might help us out here. Take a look at this **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/uoa8Lbw6/)**.

***CSS change:***

```
.label--hovered { background: green; }
```

instead of:

```
label:hover { background: green; }
```

i.e. converted it to a class.

***JavaScript:***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label').hover(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('style').addClass('label--hovered');
    }, function(){
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default').removeClass('label--hovered');
    }).click(function(){
        $(this).trigger('mouseleave');
    });
});
```

Does this help?

Comment: I agree that your answer is correct, but I do not want to use jQuery for this. I use the checkbox hack because I want to do something with Pure CSS, and I'm trying to understand it without any third parties.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the syntax for the `transition` property but on `transform`.  Additionally, `transform` doesn't take a top value.  It takes scale, rotation, skew etc.  You probably want this:

```
transition: top .3s ease;
```

Also don't forget to add vendor prefixes. (ie. webkit).

Comment: I updated the commented code, but if you try the demo you'll see that the problem happens with the right property (i.e. transition).